# PHP Array Unset Issue

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a solution to unset array keys.
How can I get this working without any php notice?

Thanks

Notice:  Undefined offset: 2099 in test1.php on line 102

```
$words = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','0987');


foreach ($words as $key => $value){
    if (preg_match('/[0-9]{4,7}/',$value)){
    unset($words[$key]);
    }
}

$array_a = array(
array('surname'=>'a'),
array('surname'=>'b'),
array('surname'=>'c')
);

$array_b = $words ;


for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_b); $i++){
    if ( count( $array_a[$i % count($array_a)] ) = 1 ){ 
        echo '<pre>';
        echo $array_a[$i % count($array_a)]['surname'] . '    ' . $array_b[$i];
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use another array?

Comment: @jcho360 What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: line 102 is just for an example

Comment: @Madbreaks he wants to "for a solution to unset array keys." he could use another array instead of unset.

Comment: The problem is not with `unset`. `unset` does not produce this kind of notice. `unset($array[$non_existant_key])` never throws such notice.

Comment: You're assigning the result of count() to one.

Comment: @JulioFong line 102 is not "just an example".  It is the line where your code is causing the PHP notice.  So which line is 102?

Comment: @jcho360 That's silly.  Unset is perfectly valid.  Using an extra array incurs additional, unneeded overhead.  Your suggestion is not a fix, it's a lazy workaround.

Comment: I think the problem is on echo whitch is trying to echo an array key that has been removed $array_b[$i]

Comment: guys I will not put an array list with 3000 elements here, that's crazy!!

Comment: You still haven't told us what is the code on the line where the error occurs. The error message give the line number to be able to quickly know where the error occured, and more easily locate what is causing the problem.

Comment: on line 102: echo $array_a[$i % count($array_a)]['surname'] . '    ' . $array_b[$i];

Answer (score 1):

Interesting! You need to use native function [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Try something like this:

```
$key = $i % count($array_a);
if(isset($array_a[$key]) && is_array($array_b)){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_b); $i++){
        isset($array_a[$key]['post']){
              echo '<pre>';
              echo $array_a[$key]['post'];
              echo '</pre>';
        } else {
             echo 'Some message error!';
        }
    }

} else {
    echo 'Some message error!';
}
```